# CGMiner, share sizes, what does a shares size with a G appended mean, how much larger than a M (million) share is it?

Tags: litecoin, mining-pool-shares, difficulty

Well I think I can retire mining now, I how produced this huge hash overnight

[image]

So, I have looked everywhere. How much is a G share in comparison to a M (million) share? There is no logical step from million to anything with G in it.

Answer (score 1):

G is short for "giga" (billions), just like M is short for "mega" (millions). Congratulations on a very lucky find that, sadly, won't pay you any more than any other share.